# How to build a next.js app with docker using appDir?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, next.js

The [with-docker](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker) example only shows how to build for `pages` dir but I haven't found and info on how to build for `app` dir.
My project is using `app` dir with `src` dir so the relevant files are located in `src/app`. It runs ok with `npm run build` -> `npm start` or `npm run dev`.

I have tried using the following Dockerfile (adapted from the example)

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
RUN npm ci

FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm run build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

with the following next.config.js

```js
const nextConfig = {
    output: "standalone"
};
```

It gives the following error when executing `npm run build` at `builder` stage

```
Couldn't find any `pages` or `app` directory. Please create one under the project root
```

So I have tried creating an empty `pages` directory and I got it to build but when running it, I only get `404`s for every route. I guess that's because It build thinking I was using `pages` instead of `src/app`. Is there any official way to make it work using appDir or am I doing something wrong here?